# 'Invalid use of group function' when using mysqli_query but not when using MySql directly

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, left-join

TLDR:
I'm getting a `MySQL` `Invalid use of group function` error when I use PHP's `mysqli_query` but not when I paste the exact same query in to MySQL directly.

Say I have the following tables:

```
customer
customer_help_request
customer_help_request_status
```

Where `customer` can have many `customer_help_request` (like when you write in with a help request on a website). `customer_help_request` can have many `custom_help_request_status`, which keeps track of the status of the help request (ex. Pending, Needs further investigation, Email sent, etc.).

I have a query to find customers that have help requests in certain states. One case where I get a `Invalid use of group function`:

(FYI: The query is programmatically built from multiple conditions that a user selects, so the shape of the query will not always be exactly like this. The having clauses might differ, for example, depending on what type of filtering was selected in the UI)

```
SELECT r.customer_id FROM customer_help_request AS r
  JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, help_request_id FROM customer_help_request
    WHERE help_request_id IN (
      SELECT help_request_id FROM customer_help_request
      GROUP BY help_request_id
      HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN request_closed_date <> "" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
    ) AND
    (request_type_id IN ("2"))
    GROUP BY customer_id, help_request_id
  ) AS open_requests
  ON open_requests.help_request_id = r.help_request_id AND open_requests.help_request_id = r.help_request_id
  LEFT JOIN customer_help_request_status AS rs
  ON rs.help_request_id = r.help_request_id
  GROUP BY r.help_request_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.request_type_id = 2 AND STR_TO_DATE(rs.date, "%m/%d/%Y") >= STR_TO_DATE("02/19/2019", '%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(rs.date, "%m/%d/%Y") <= STR_TO_DATE("02/20/2019", '%m/%d/%Y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

I'm not the greatest at wrapping my head around joins, subqueries, and derived tables, so I'm looking for both help in spotting the error in my query (if there is one), as well as better ideas for how to achieve what I'm after. Also, any insight as to why PHP's `mysqli` would throw an error, but when I dump that query, and paste it directly in to a MySQL prompt, I get no error and I get valid results.

Comment: Have you tried looking up that error message? I'd assume that there is a difference in the SQL modes which are used by either the PHP script or the MySQL shell

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, I've looked up the error message. I've tried to determine what the SQL mode is for mysqli, but to no avail. Regardless, I'd be curious to figure out why I'm getting that error in the first place. There must be something wrong with my query, but I'm having a hard time spotting it.

Comment: Does the query return whatever you expect when you run it using the MySQL shell? Have you tried reducing the given array down to the simplest parts that throw that error message?

Comment: Yes to both of those questions.

Comment: I would try to prefix all fields with table prefixes, so MySQL will know exactly in which table the columns are.
Then enxt thing is to check what exactly is APN? Is it a field in your table?

Comment: @papazulu That APN was actually a typo - I've edited it - I had replaced the actual column names with ones that were easier to understand (I'm working on a project that was handed down to me, and I don't have the power to rename all the crappily named columns). I'll try your idea to prefix fields. Do you mean in the query or in the actual schema?

Comment: @Charlotte, I meant just in the query, for example `SELECT chr.customer_id, chr.help_request_id FROM customer_help_request chr
    WHERE chr.help_request_id ...` and so on, especially in the GROUP BY statements. Let us know if it works :)